# List Workflow doesn't fire if site permissions assigned to group?

Tags: workflow, permissions

I'm trying to debug an incredibly frustrating scenario here and I'm at my wit's end.

I have a simple SharePoint 2013 site with two lists.  There is a workflow attached to the first list that is supposed to fire on Item Created and Item Changed that creates an item in the second list.

There is a specific set of users that need to use this site.  These users are all in an Active Directory Global Security group.  Naturally, I gave this group Contributor site permissions.  And by virtue of having such permission, have the ability to add and edit list items.

The workflow never fires.

The users are able to create list items in the first list, as designed and intended, perfectly fine.  However, the workflow never fires and the item in the second list never gets created.

However, as soon as I assign Contribute site permissions to the individual users, the workflow fires as intended and the items get created in the second list.  It works.

Obviously, this is not optimal as it completely defeats the purpose of group-based security.

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If your workflow fires when you dont set the permission, try remove group permission and add worklow step for item based permission.

1. Workflow starts. (item created or item changed)
2. Create item in the second list.
3. Set created item permission.

Actually i want add comment but i have not enough reputation. But i think you must check first this problem really caused by permission settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use the impersonating step in the workflow, so you don't need to worry about the permissions. It will skip the permissions but still having your users as the level restricted you want them.